# How to upload an app bundle of 200 mb that has no assets

Tags: mobile

I am trying to upload an aab in the play store that is over 200mb, the app does not contain any assets, the size comes only from the tensorflow libraries, how can i upload this app?

Is there a way to dynamically download the neccessary content?